# Find the process is in cache or buffer

Tags: linux

I am running web and DB on a single server with 4GB ram. When I checked memory using free -m I can see most of the memory is in cached.

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3534        1507         973          25        1052        1676
Swap:          8191           0        8191
```

Is there any way to find out which process is served from cache or which are getting a cache, because everytime I have to use sync command to clear free memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should *not* do that. *Free memory is unused memory*, a wasted resource. The kernel knows what it's doing: as long as there is no better use for memory it will use it for I/O buffers or disk cache. When a process more memory will be needed for running processes then the kernel will automatically allocate it.

Unless you can *measure* an imbalance between the use of swap space and memory you should not interfere with the memory allocation parameters.